# Drop down is not working in Angular after adding child routes

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Here is  my part of app.component.html (here I have added end of the code router-outlet)

```
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" routerLink='courses' routerLinkActive='active'
               id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown" >
                Courses
              </a>

              <div class="dropdown-menu" >
                <a class="dropdown-item"  routerLink='java' routerLinkActive='active'>Java</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink='spring' routerLinkActive='active'>Springboot</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink='node' routerLinkActive='active'>NodeJs</a>
              </div>
            </li>
```

Here is my app-routing.module.ts file

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CoursesComponent} from './courses/courses.component';
import {PagenotfoundComponent} from './pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';
import { JavaComponent } from './java/java.component';
import { NodejsComponent } from './nodejs/nodejs.component';
import { SpringbootComponent } from './springboot/springboot.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'courses', component: CoursesComponent,
  children: [
    {path: 'java', component: JavaComponent},
    {path: 'spring', component: SpringbootComponent},
    {path: 'node', component: NodejsComponent}
  ]},

  {path: '** ', component: PagenotfoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My drop down bar is not working

Comment: What errors is it giving you?

Comment: and shouldn't the routerLink be like `routerLink='courses/java'`?

Comment: @Kinglish I have not get any error. But my drop down menu is not working

Comment: @Kinglish i have tried `routerLink='courses/java'` . but it still not working

Comment: What library are you using for your dropdown?

Comment: @Silvermind I have used bootstrap

Comment: What doesn't work? the animation of dropdown or the redirection of router link to the child?

Comment: @SamanthikaRajapaksa Which one? ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap or plain old bootstrap with jquery?

Comment: router will capture your click event and prevent bubbling; you need to manually add class "show" along with "dropdown-toggle" class and "dropdown-menu"  to make it visible. remove it to hide dropdown respectively.

Comment: @AntonioEsposito animation of drop down

Comment: @Silvermind old bootstrap with jquery. I have upgrade my angular version.Afeter that it will happen

Comment: Then I would suggest that you switch to one of the versions created specifically for Angular, if you can. jQuery and Angular don't work well together, because jQuery works with references to DOM elements, while Angular updates the DOM with new elements all the time. So these references are lost.